# Modify Flash movie without fla files or decompilers

Tags: flash, actionscript

I have been asked to add just some more text in the last "slide" of a Flash movie. I don't have access to the .fla files. What are my options (apart from using decompilers)? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing you can do to the original, perhaps you could get messy and create a new swf load the other swf into the back and time your text to appear on the new swf in the right place.

Answer (score 0):

Well I think you can load the swf into the fla. Something like

```
function startLoad()
{
var mLoader:Loader = new Loader();
var mRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest(“OldFlashMovie.swf”);
mLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onCompleteHandler);
mLoader.load(mRequest);
}

function onCompleteHandler(loadEvent:Event)
{
addChild(loadEvent.currentTarget.content);
}
```

You can also add it directly into the library of the new fla as a movie clip. Pull the clip into the timespan of current fla & add more stuff.

---

If you consider the later option, here is an example. (Add it to the first frame of the new fla)

```
stop();

var obj:MovieClip;

obj = new oldClip();
obj.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, _handle);

addChild(obj);

function _handle(e:Event):void
{
    if(obj.currentFrame == obj.totalFrames)
    {   
        obj.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, _handle);        
        removeChild(obj);

        obj = new newClip();
        addChild(obj);
    }
}
```

Where :

**oldClip** is the old flash movie clip.

**newClip** is the new clip containing  your text addition.

No need to drag drop anything onto stage. Let the clips be inside library and set export to actionscript with the class names as above.

Comment: Many thanks, I've trying the latter. Can you tell me how to via actionscript get to the last "frame" of the imported movie clip and add the text there (keeping all objects there). Sorry I'm new to Flash.

Comment: @netNewbi3 You cannot modify the original movie clip. I suggest that you add the movie clip into the first frame of the new fla & add other stuff into subsequent frames. Also in actionscript, you use timers & do not have any frames as such.

Comment: sorry I expressed my thoughts badly. I wanted if possible ask you for the actioscript code I need to load the movie clip, detect when the movie clip ends and make the new frame with the text appears. Thanks!